# EmberJS modifying REST adapter for JSON-API standards

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've just come to Ember from Marionette, however I'm struggleing to overwrite the way Ember parses API responses in the REST adapter. I need to modify it to use the JSON-API (http://jsonapi.org/) specification as my API's are implemented with it.

Comment: You need to change the serializer in application.js.. I you are using ember-cli, then in app/serializer/application.js add following changes:..... 
export default DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend();

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is an ember-data adapter being developed to address your problem. See [here](https://github.com/kurko/ember-json-api)

You will need to

1. `npm install`
2. import the adapter and serializer

and then you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this could be useful for you: 
http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONSerializer.html